# Trying to save coordinates from maps

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, maps

Im retreiving coordinates via HTML5. But when I try to save the coordinates with an AJAX post nothing is inserted.
savespot.php does work, so maybe its problem with the ajax post?
Or is ajax post run before coordinates is retrieved?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <body>
        <p id="demo">Click the button to get your position:</p>
        <button onclick="getLocation()">Get your location</button>
        <div id="mapholder"></div>
        <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
        <script>
            var x=document.getElementById("demo");
            function getLocation()
            {
                if (navigator.geolocation)
                {
                    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition,showError);
                }
                else{x.innerHTML="Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";}
            }
            function showPosition(position)
            {
                lat=position.coords.latitude;
                lon=position.coords.longitude;
                latlon=new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon)
                mapholder=document.getElementById('mapholder')
                mapholder.style.height='250px';
                mapholder.style.width='500px';
                var myOptions={
                    center:latlon,zoom:14,
                    mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                    mapTypeControl:false,
                    navigationControlOptions:{style:google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL}
                };
                var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapholder"),myOptions);
                var marker=new google.maps.Marker({position:latlon,map:map,title:"You are here!"});
            }
            function showError(error)
            {
                switch(error.code)
                {
                    case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
                        x.innerHTML="User denied the request for Geolocation."
                        break;
                    case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
                        x.innerHTML="Location information is unavailable."
                        break;
                    case error.TIMEOUT:
                        x.innerHTML="The request to get user location timed out."
                        break;
                    case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
                        x.innerHTML="An unknown error occurred."
                        break;
                }
            }
        </script>
        <script>
            function ajaxFunction()
            { 
                $.ajax({ 
                    url:'savespot.php', 
                    type:'POST', 
                    data:'lat='+lat+'&lon='+lng, 
                    success:function(d){ 
                        console.log(d); 
                    }, 
                    error(w,t,f){ 
                        console.log(w+' '+t+' '+f); 
                    } 
                }); 
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

savespot.php

```
<?php

    include_once 'includes/db.php';

    //  $x = "52.364659"; 
    //  $y = "13.191007"; 
    $nick = "GPSTEST";
    $adress = "Odefinierat";

    $x = @$_POST['lat'];
    $y = @$_POST['lng'];


    $sql = 'INSERT INTO location ' .
            '(name, address, lat, lng, date) ' .
            'VALUES ("' . $nick . '", "' . $adress . '", "' . $x . '", "' . $y . '", NOW())';

    $retval = mysql_query($sql, $connection);
    if (!$retval) {
        die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    echo "Entered data successfully\n";
?>
```

Comment: How/when is `ajaxFunction()` called?

Comment: Added jquery to the tags. Be sure to add that next time. For solutions, why don't you try to post first with a simple form and see if the receiving script works?

Comment: And check in the console if you see an request going to savespot.php with post values.

Comment: Please try to format code before you post, so that it is readable and also people can understand what you are up to...

Comment: Praveen Kumar: The code is formated?

Comment: @andernicken I edited the code to look good.

Answer (score 1):

There is an error in your AJAX Setup.

```
$.ajax({ 
    url:'savespot.php', 
    type:'POST', 
    data:'lat='+lat+'&lon='+lng, 
    success:function(d){ 
        console.log(d); 
    }, 
    error(w,t,f){ 
        console.log(w+' '+t+' '+f); 
    } 
});
```

Should give `error:` infront of the `error(w,t,f){}`.

```
    error: error(w,t,f){ 
        console.log(w+' '+t+' '+f); 
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I cant get ajax to work.
I have tried put code after

function getLocation()

But nothing is posted. As alone script savespot.php works.

Comment: @andernicken Did you try a normal HTTP POST to the `savespot.php` and check out what is the issue? Have you got `display_errors` set as `1`?

Comment: A normal http post gives an error now?
Could not enter data: Data truncated for column 'lng' at row 1

<form method="post" action="savespot.php">
<input name="lat" value="51.324529">
<input name="lon" value="13.131307">
<input type="submit" value="Test">
</form>

Comment: How come is that error showing? I tried to change lat and lng in db from (float) 10,6 to 10,13. But all I get is an error?

Comment: Sorry! My mistake in test. (lon became lng)
HTTP POST works. Not ajax.

Comment: Did you check the response type? Is it `text/html` or `text/plain` or `application/json`?

Comment: @Praveen Kumar Dont know how to do that? Im a beginner.

Comment: All I want to do is get location from a page with html5 and store it in my MySQL-db

Comment: Im giving up this. Can a moderator please delete my question?

Comment: @andernicken Just leave it. Someone would surely be able to better guide you.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot find where/how you call `ajaxFunction`, and without knowing that I can't be sure, but my best guess is that you make the Ajax-request before the position has been retrieved.

`navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` is asynchronus, and it will wait until the user has  accepted that your page wants to retrieve their geoposition. Until they do, the function will return nothing. The best way to handle this is to make the ajax-request in the callback for `getCurrentPosition`, that way you know for sure that you have the position, before you make the call.

In your case, that would mean that you call `ajaxFunction()` from within `showPosition()`.

Comment: I am sorry, but I dont understand what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring you ajax data like this:

```
$.ajax({ 
  url:'savespot.php', 
  type:'POST', 
  data:{
    lat:lat,
    lon:lng
  }
});
```

Answer (score -2):

I think that the variables lat and lon should be declared with a global scope or in other words you need to declare it out of the showPosition() function.